# Lilith and Bloodshot Stronghold

Tags: borderlands-2

Apparently I dropped down from the area I was transported to by Lilith and I cannot find how to get back there, so that I can get to the Bloodshot Stronghold now i'm lost. Is there another way to get there? Is there a way to find Lilith and ask her to transport me there again? Apparently I was supposed to stay where she transported me to and walk down the steps from that area where there is a trunk/chest and two lockers on the left. Not the area where there is the vending machines.

Comment: Could you possibly provide a screenshot?

Comment: I do not know how to make a screenshot or add it to this post. However the area is where I meet Lilith for the first time and she wants Eridium circular area with two sets of steps it turned out that when she transported me 10 feet away it was to a platform above I found I could get up on top of something in the original area (not stairs) and look around and I saw the platform and the area I need to be at but could not figure out how to get there.

Comment: I recommend you write shorter sentences. It's hard to read when it flows from one sentence into the other. You got teleported 10 feet, and then you're supposed to walk up the tunnel and out of her cave through a rear entrance (the only way you can go after she teleports you). Then you exit the canyon and drive off to the Bloodshot Stronghold area. Also, you take screenshots with the key "PrtSc" or any abbreviation of "Print Screen". Then... well, upload it to imgur by either pasting it in there or pasting it into Paint, saving the Image, and then uploading it to a site like Imgur.

Comment: you don`t have to go back up after transported, you only need to go back to Santcuary.

Answer (score 1):

If you fell down from that path, then you've missed some loot, but that's it. You just need to go back to Sanctuary to continue the quest.

If you really want to go back to get the loot, you'll have to run all the way back the same way you came the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Man, i encountered the same problem with one of my characters.
Don't worry, it's actually part of the story.
Lilith actually fails to teleport you, placing your character just a few meters away from previous position (her lair).
Just go back to frostburn canyon and follow the mission indications, you'll be fine (..mission to the Dust, new car, bla bla...).
In a couple of missions you'll be entering the Bloodshot Stronghold.

A little tip: before going in... level up. Quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible to jump to that platform from the side you start out on (on PS3 and PS4 at least). It isn't easy, and probably not worth it since there's only a chest and a couple ammo/cash boxes, but I have done it.